# initComplete modification to datatable not rendering on app initialization

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which renders two data tables, each of which should have a different colored header. I know how to change the color of an individual table's header using custom javascript in the `initComplete` argument in `DT::datatable(options)`.

However, for some reason, when I first run the application in a new RStudio session, only one table's header has the color changed. As shown in the gif below, when I click refresh, the color correctly changes, and if the app is closed and then re-run, it renders correctly, but this behavior always happens on first execution in a new session which I would like to avoid.

Is there a way to change the java code to avoid this happening?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
  dataTableOutput("tbl2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl1 <- renderDataTable(mtcars %>%
                                   head(n = 5) %>%
                                   datatable(options(
                                     initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                                       "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'green'});",
                                                       "}"))))
  output$tbl2 <- renderDataTable(mtcars %>%
                                   head(n = 5) %>%
                                   datatable(options(
                                     initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                                       "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'red'});",
                                                       "}"))))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
    dataTableOutput("tbl2"),
    tags$script(
        "
        $('#tbl1').on('preInit.dt', function () {
            $(this).find('thead').css({'background-color': 'green'});
        });
        $('#tbl2').on('preInit.dt', function () {
            $(this).find('thead').css({'background-color': 'red'});
        });
        "
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$tbl1 <- renderDataTable(mtcars %>%
                                       head(n = 5) %>%
                                       datatable())
    output$tbl2 <- renderDataTable(mtcars %>%
                                       head(n = 5) %>%
                                       datatable())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

##### update

If you want to apply all tables with the same color at once, use this

```r
    tags$script(
        "
        $('.datatables.html-widget').on('preInit.dt', function () {
            $(this).find('thead').css({'background-color': 'green'});
        });
        "
    )
```

Add this tag after you define all tables, have to be after not before.

Comment: Thank you @lz100. One follow-up question. Is there anyway to universally apply that script to all tables in an application? I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to apply your solution to a modularized application, but it's only changing the header color of one table. Is there anyway to modify the code so that you do not have to specify the table ID, and instead simply apply that to any and all data tables? Perhaps just calling the function once, instead of once for each table? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to apply it on all tables, but it means all tables will have the same color for the header. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yup, I do recognize that runs completely counter to my original question, but now I'm seeing that the solution might just be tables with the same color for the actual business use case. If you want, I can create a new question and ping you on that one.

Comment: @DJC see my edits